# Matching paragraph with line breaks Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What regex can I use to match a paragraph (including line breaks) so when I use `split()`, I get an array with each sentence as one element?

Something like this:

```
const paragraph = `
  one potatoe
  two apples
  three onions
`;

const arr = paragraph.split(/(.+?\n\n|.+?$)/);
```

I have that regex that returns `["one potatoe↵two apples↵", "three onions", ""]` but what I'm looking for is `["one potatoe", "two apples", "three onions"]`.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**:

Each sentence is separated by a line break. So after `one potatoe` there's a line break (hit return) and then comes `two apples`, line break and `three onions`

Comment: What is the definition of a sentence? I mean, if it were `"I bought↵one patatoe↵two apples↵three onions↵and a bag today"`... then what?

Comment: This was just an hypothetical example. My goal is to separate each sentence of any paragraph that I feed to the Regex into their own element on an array @trincot . So imagine that ```one potatoe``` is one sentence, ```two apples``` another, and so on, with no relation of one sentence with the next or previous one

Comment: Your regex has `\n\n` instead of just `\n`, so it doesn't match the newlines in your string. Furthermore the regex doesn't have the `/m` flag, which means the `$` can only match at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you want to get each line with text with as many adjacent line breaks as follow it.

It will be easier to use `match` instead of `split`:

```js
const paragraph = `
one potatoe
two apples

three onions`;

const arr = paragraph.match(/^.+$[\n\r]*/gm);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, @trincot